# Is there an alternative to Dockerfile Env Instruction?

Tags: docker

In their official site (https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env), Docker support state that:

> The ENV instruction sets the environment variable  to the value
>   . This value will be passed to all future RUN instructions.
>   **This is functionally equivalent to prefixing the command with < key >=< value >**

I tried:

```
http_proxy=<PROXY> docker build .
```

However, this doesn't seem to bring the same effect as adding ENV http_proxy=< PROXY > inside the Dockerfile. Why ???

Comment: a basic `$ docker run -e HTTP_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4 -it ubuntu:latest env` shows 
`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=9fac87569e56
TERM=xterm
HTTP_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4
HOME=/root
` so passing a value to a `run -e ... ` works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **This is functionally equivalent to prefixing the command with < key >=< value >**

This does not mean it is the same as prefixing `docker build` command since It is command executed outside of a container.

It means using ENV is the same as prefixing commands that run *inside container.*

For example, equivalent RUN statement would look like this:

```
RUN http_proxy=<PROXY> curl https://www.google.com
```

Or equivalent command executed inside container (via shell):

```
$ http_proxy=<PROXY> curl https://www.google.com
```

Comment: It's also not quite correct. They're not functionally equivalent. Setting the environment value inline in the `RUN` command only sets it for that run. Setting it in a distinct `ENV` command sets it for all future commands, including containers based off the built image.

Comment: OK, but I can't upvote you twice. :P FWIW I created a [pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/10273) to tweak the documentation about `ENV` vs inline.